# Data tables com bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-datatables

Alguem tem algum tutorial simples de aplicar o data table no bootstrap,tentei das formas que tem no site mas não consegui, com skell css funcionou perfeitamente mas com bootstrap não aparece.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dataTables.bootstrap.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable();
        } );
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O processo é bem simples e está disponível no site da [DataTables](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html). Basta importar todos os arquivos na sequencia correta.

1. jQuery >= [1.12](http:////code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js)
2. Bootstrap [JS](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js) / [CSS](http:////maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css)
3. [DataTables](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js)
4. [Estilo Bootstrap para datatables](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css)

Segue o [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/xF8hZ/577/) de tudo importado e funcionando, qualquer duvida pode falar :)

Comment: por incrivel que pareça nao consegui copiei certinho fiz as referencias mas mesmo assim não funciona kkk

Comment: não sei se erá aonde eu inicializava o javascript da id da table, antes estava colocando no começo da tabela, copiei do jeito que vc mandou e funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado parceiro